# Выделить совпадение в массиве

Tags: массивы, php, foreach

Всем привет.

Что-то никак не могу понять как сделать. Может не вижу очевидного?

У меня есть массив (может быть сколько угодно)
array(1 => 100, 2 => 200, 3 => 300)

он обрабатывается в цикле и выводит таблицу

Есть число 250

Мне нужно в этом цикле выделить то, что больше 200 и меньше 300
т.е. до 300 мы не дотягиваем, но уже перевалили 200.

Для наглядности приведу готовый код

```
$a = array(1 => 100, 2 => 200, 3 => 300, 4 => 400);
$b = 250;

foreach ($a AS $k => $v)
{
    $i = ($b >= $v) ? ' - yes' : '';
    echo "item {$v}{$i}<br />";
}
```

Залип. Выделяет естественно и 1 элемент, так как он меньше $b

Как быть? Элементарная вроде задача, а залип намертво.
Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: @Deonis

Вот у меня массив array(1 => 100, 2 => 200, 3 => 300, 4 => 400); по которому я прохожу циклом.

У меня есть фиксированное число 267

Вернуть true нужно тогда, когда число 267 меньше 300, но больше 200

В случае, если у нас вместо 267 будет 300, то вернуть должно true в когда в цикле будет значение 300.

Образно, пример.

Человек набрал определенное количество очков. За очки мы даем ему бонусы.

Бонусы имеют категории: 1000, 5000, 1000, 15500

Вот когда чел набрал определенное количество очков бонусов, то нужно выделить определенный бонус.

Comment: @drop_off, не знаю зачем вам там циклы и нет уже сил бороться, посему [делаю еще одну попытку][1] и, если нет, то пардоньте, но я пас.

   [1]:http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/y5t-v0x

Comment: @Deonis прошу прощения, если не понятно как-то объяснил.

Сделал пример http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/yst-w3q

У меня $current = 250;. Т.е. активное в таблице должно быть 200

А у меня там еще подсвечивает 100, что не нужно.

Если $current будет 300 или 315 или 399, то подсветить нужно 300. Так как до 400 еще не добрались, а 200 уже прошли.

$current >= определенного значения массива, то выделяем его.

В любом случае спасибо Вам за помощь. Буду ковыряться.

Answer (score 1):

```
function closest($array, $number){

    //Удобнее работать с числовыми ключами
    $array = array_values($array);
    //Добавляем наше число в конец массива
    $array[] = $number;

    //Сортируем массив
    sort($array);
    //Получаем ключ массива, соответствующий нашему числу
    $key = array_search($number, $array, true);

    //Возвращаем предыдущий элемент массива
    //Это и есть ближайшее число
    if($key && isset($array[$key-1])) {
        return $array[$key-1];
    }

    return null;
}

$a = array(1 => 100, 2 => 500, 3 => 3000, 4 => 20000,  5 => 50000);
$b = 20000;
$closest = closest($a, $b);

foreach ($a AS $k => $v)
{   
    $i = ($v >= $closest && $v <= $b) ? ' - yes' : '';
    echo "item {$v}{$i}<br />";
}

#item 100
#item 500
#item 3000 - yes
#item 20000 - yes
#item 50000
```

Comment: Спасибо.

Но если такое, то не работает
$a = array(1 => 1000, 2 => 5000, 3 => 50000);
$b = 26990;

Comment: Обновил свой ответ. Выделяются числа от ближайшего слева до самого искомого числа.

Comment: Получается, если $b = 20000, то выделяется и 3000.

нужно выделять только одно 20000

чет не понимаю я как это все работает) буду вникать сейчас.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте [такой вариант](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/k48-g75). Там понамешано, но выберите нужное и что-то возможно подойдет.

P.S. Перейдя по ссылке, нажмите F9 или Run

Comment: Спасибо. Но там php 5.3 нужен? у меня php 5.2 и обновить не вариант.

Comment: Если только в этом проблема, то можно и [под 5.2 адаптировать][1]

   [1]:http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/gpc-s71

Comment: Вроде то, что нужно. Только как применить в контексте с моим кодом?

Что-то не пойму.

Comment: @drop_off, и я вас не пойму )) 

Есть заданное число **N** и массив чисел **A**. Задача: надо получить из массива **A** ... ***продожите фразу***

Comment: Вопрос в том, как мне в цикле (массив N), в нужной итерации получить из closestNum($arr, $num) true, если туда идет не текущее число из массива, а сам массив. Т.е. сейчас никак не определить какое значение массива совпало)

Comment: @drop_off, Например, [таким образом][1]

   [1]:http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/dv6-g85

Comment: Так получается

Item 200 - yes

Item 300 - yes

мы указываем 243, до 300 не дошли, выделять нужно только 200

ух что-то простая задача, какая-то не совсем простая)

Comment: @drop_off, на самом деле, адаптировать вариант под разные задачи - это уже не проблема. Лично я не могу втянуться до конца, что же вам надо. Смотрите [такой вариант][1].

   [1]:http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/zkc-9pd